# How NOT to send email to "Activity Assignee" when assigned an activity

Tags: email, activities, best-practice

Usually we create different type of activities and assigned to one of our volunteer. Now when "Create separate activity for each contact" is selected, assignee volunteer receive multiple emails for each contact.

Alternative option is not to check that option, but then it creates only one activity for multiple contacts, and when changed the status of activity of 1 contact, it changes status of all contacts.

I know emails can be redirected to database, I guess by doing that all offline contribution email receipt wouldn't be sent right?

So Is there a option or a way NOT to send a email notification to a assignee without compromising any other outbound email service?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In CiviCRM Administration > Display Preferences you can turn off emails to activity assignees globally

civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: and Display Preferences seems a weird place for this which is why i never remember where to look. thanks